# The result of xor(true, true, true) of the BooleanUtils class under the commons-lang toolkit under Apache is false, why?

Tags: apache-commons-lang

The result of **xor(true, true, true)** of the **BooleanUtils** class under the **commons-lang** toolkit under Apache is **false**, but the result of **System.out.println(true ^ true ^ true)** is **true**. Why?

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang.BooleanUtils.xor(new boolean[]{true, true, true}));
        System.out.println(org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils.xor(new boolean[]{true, true, true}));
        System.out.println(true ^ true ^ true);
    }
}
/*
    result:
    false
    false
    true
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason you are seeing this behavior is that you are using an older version of commons-lang (< 3.2).

Newer versions behave [the same as Java](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/105a350b154eac7c3f3a6bac94ec2cfb0fbe232b/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.java#L1092) (i.e. it evaluates one xor at a time from left to right).

The older versions used a [different approach](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/105a350b154eac7c3f3a6bac94ec2cfb0fbe232b/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.java#L1092) however: They return true only if there is **exactly one** true value in the entire array.

This behavior was considered incorrect (see [LANG-921](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-921)) and has since been fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have checked the source code of this method from the latest [GitHub address](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.java) and fixed the problem.

Comment: @mochen if this has answered your question then please mark it as accepted.